# Third level onChange event not working.state list shown but cities not reflecting

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<select id="region" onchange="ChangeStateList()">
  <option value="">-- Region --</option>
  <option value="ANY">ANY</option>
  <option value="North_DEL">North_DEL</option>
  <option value="North_HR">North_HR</option>
  <option value="South_TN">South_TN</option>
  <option value="South_KK">South_KK</option>
</select>

<select onchange="ChangeCityList()" id="state"></select>


<select id="city"></select>

<script>
  var regionAndStates = {};
  regionAndStates['ANY'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi', 'Haryana', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Karnataka'];
  regionAndStates['North_DEL'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi'];
  regionAndStates['North_HR'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Haryana'];
  regionAndStates['South_TN'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Tamil Nadu'];
  regionAndStates['South_KK'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Karnataka'];


  function ChangeStateList() {
    var regionList = document.getElementById("region");
    var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
    var selState = regionList.options[regionList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (stateList.options.length) {
      stateList.remove(0);
    }
    var states = regionAndStates[selState];
    if (states) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        var state = new Option(states[i], i);
        stateList.options.add(state);
      }
    }
  }


  function ChangeCityList() {
    var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
    var cityList = document.getElementById("city");
    var selCity = stateList.options[stateList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (cityList.options.length) {
      cityList.remove(0);
    }
    var cities = stateAndCities[selCity];
    if (cities) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var city = new Option(cities[i], i);
        cityList.options.add(city);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

State list is showing perfectly on basis of region selected but cities drop down is not working.First `onChange` event `ChangeStateList()` is working fine but second `onChange` event `ChangeCityList()` is not triggered. I am new to JavaScript. Please suggest changes in code. I don't want to do it with ajax. Suggest using basic JavaScript only.

Comment: Where did you defined `stateAndCities`?

Comment: sorry... i forgot pasting that while asking question...This is actual code snippet. var cityAndStates = {};
cityAndStates['ANY'] = ['--City--','ANY',, 'Karol Bagh','Indraprastha','Patel Nagar','Baroda House', 'Palam Vihar','Air Force','Jharsa','Gwal Pahari'];
cityAndStates['Delhi'] = ['--City--','ANY', 'Karol Bagh','Indraprastha','Patel Nagar','Baroda House'];
cityAndStates['Haryana'] = ['--City--','ANY', 'Palam Vihar','Air Force','Jharsa','Gwal Pahari'];
cityAndStates['Tamil Nadu'] = ['--City--','ANY'];
cityAndStates['Karnataka'] = ['--City--','ANY'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using index as value while appending options to state drop down which is not matching with your source array. Change your state drop down option value to text instead of `i`

```js
    var cityAndStates = {};
        cityAndStates['ANY'] = ['--City--', 'ANY', , 'Karol Bagh', 'Indraprastha', 'Patel Nagar', 'Baroda House', 'Palam Vihar', 'Air Force', 'Jharsa', 'Gwal Pahari'];
        cityAndStates['Delhi'] = ['--City--', 'ANY', 'Karol Bagh', 'Indraprastha', 'Patel Nagar', 'Baroda House'];
        cityAndStates['Haryana'] = ['--City--', 'ANY', 'Palam Vihar', 'Air Force', 'Jharsa', 'Gwal Pahari'];
        cityAndStates['Tamil Nadu'] = ['--City--', 'ANY'];
        cityAndStates['Karnataka'] = ['--City--', 'ANY'];
        var regionAndStates = {};
        regionAndStates['ANY'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi', 'Haryana', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Karnataka'];
        regionAndStates['North_DEL'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi'];
        regionAndStates['North_HR'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Haryana'];
        regionAndStates['South_TN'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Tamil Nadu'];
        regionAndStates['South_KK'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Karnataka'];
    
    
        function ChangeStateList() {
            var regionList = document.getElementById("region");
            var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
            var selState = regionList.options[regionList.selectedIndex].value;
            while (stateList.options.length) {
                stateList.remove(0);
            }
            var states = regionAndStates[selState];
            if (states) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
                    var state = new Option(states[i], states[i]);
                    stateList.options.add(state);
                }
            }
        }
    
    
        function ChangeCityList() {
            var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
            var cityList = document.getElementById("city");
            var selCity = stateList.options[stateList.selectedIndex].value;
            while (cityList.options.length) {
                cityList.remove(0);
            }
            var cities = cityAndStates[selCity];
            if (cities) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                    var city = new Option(cities[i], i);
                    cityList.options.add(city);
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<select id="region" onchange="ChangeStateList()">
  <option value="">-- Region --</option>
  <option value="ANY">ANY</option>
  <option value="North_DEL">North_DEL</option>
  <option value="North_HR">North_HR</option>
  <option value="South_TN">South_TN</option>
  <option value="South_KK">South_KK</option>
</select>

<select onchange="ChangeCityList()" id="state"></select>


<select id="city"></select>
```

Comment: in `ChangeStateList` function change  `var state = new Option(states[i], i);` to `var state = new Option(states[i], states[i]);`

Comment: I m getting city in variables 1,2,3,4 and not names. Please help.

Comment: which variables?

Answer (score 0):

stateAndCities is not defined:

```html
<select id="region" onchange="ChangeStateList()">
  <option value="">-- Region --</option>
  <option value="ANY">ANY</option>
  <option value="North_DEL">North_DEL</option>
  <option value="North_HR">North_HR</option>
  <option value="South_TN">South_TN</option>
  <option value="South_KK">South_KK</option>
</select>

<select onchange="ChangeCityList()" id="state"></select>


<select id="city"></select>

<script>
  var regionAndStates = {};
  regionAndStates['ANY'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi', 'Haryana', 'Tamil Nadu', 'Karnataka'];
  regionAndStates['North_DEL'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Delhi'];
  regionAndStates['North_HR'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Haryana'];
  regionAndStates['South_TN'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Tamil Nadu'];
  regionAndStates['South_KK'] = ['--State--', 'ANY', 'Karnataka'];


  function ChangeStateList() {
    var regionList = document.getElementById("region");
    var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
    var selState = regionList.options[regionList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (stateList.options.length) {
      stateList.remove(0);
    }
    var states = regionAndStates[selState];
    if (states) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        var state = new Option(states[i], i);
        stateList.options.add(state);
      }
    }
  }


  function ChangeCityList() {
    var stateList = document.getElementById("state");
    var cityList = document.getElementById("city");
    var selCity = stateList.options[stateList.selectedIndex].value;
    while (cityList.options.length) {
      cityList.remove(0);
    }
    var cities = selCity;
    if (cities) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var city = new Option(cities[i], i);
        cityList.options.add(city);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```